# can not call completion block, but it has to be called

Tags: swift

I have a very strange thing going on

```
func playAudio(url: URL, completion: (URL) -> ()) {
        if savedFiles.contains(where: { $0.key == url }) {
            let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let audioFileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
            
            do {
                let data = savedFiles[url]
                try data?.write(to: audioFileURL)
                completion(audioFileURL)
            } catch {
                delegate?.didCatchError()
            }
        } else {
            downloadSong(url: url) { [weak self] result in
                guard let self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let result):
                    if let url = result.first?.key {
                        self.playAudio(url: url, completion: { _ in })
                    }
                default: break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

if I set breakpoint on completion(audioFileUrl), I see that everything is fine, but

```
trackDownloader.playAudio(url: url) { [weak self] url in
                print("lala")
                guard let self else { return }
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                self.playerToggle(play: isPlaying)
                self.startPlayTimestamp = startPlayTimestamp.getTimeStamp()
                self.createProgressObserver()
            }
```

breakpoint is on print("lala") doesn't work ever. Song is not playing and so on... why?...

Comment: Not every path of execution inside `playAudio` calls the completion handler. So there is a very real chance it is never called.

Comment: but breakpoint is here completion(audioFileURL)

Comment: maybe self is not available anymore

Comment: There may also be an issue with which thread the recursive call is made on. Does `downloadSong` call its completion handler on the main thread? If not, you will be accessing variables from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the content is not cached and downloaded for the first time, because of this code

```
self.playAudio(url: url, completion: { _ in })
```

Here we are calling the `playAudio` method recursively and passing the callback method which does nothing, it is actually overwriting the value on completion and instead of calling the method provided here

```
trackDownloader.playAudio(url: url)
```

it just calls `{ _ in }`

So we need to pass on the same reference passing the callback from the first call like this.

```
self.playAudio(url: url, completion: completion)
```

Answer (score 0):

A human being cannot work with completion handlers very easily. Switch.

```swift
func playAudio(url: URL) async throws -> URL {
  if savedFiles.contains(where: { $0.key == url }) {
    do {
      let audioFileURL = URL.documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
      try savedFiles[url]?.write(to: audioFileURL)
      return audioFileURL
    } catch {
      delegate?.didCatchError()
      throw error
    }
  } else if let url = try await downloadSong(url: url).first?.key {
    return try await playAudio(url: url)
  } else {
    // Throw some error. I don't know what it represents to not have a URL at this point.
  }
}

func downloadSong(url: URL) async throws -> [URL: Data] {
```